# How to stop/interrupt running thread from another method?

Tags: java, android, runnable

I am a total beginner to android and Java development, and I am currently trying to make a metronome.
The first problem I encountered after getting the sound playback to work, is that whenever the metronome played the app would stop responding - that's when I learned about threads and how I should use a new thread for my audio playback.

Creating a new thread helped and now the app runs fine, but I can't get the thread to stop/interrupt. I've read maybe 50 articles already about threads and interrupts and I can't figure it out.

Here is my 'Player' class code, which I've mostly copied from another Stack Overflow post (I have tried countless other ways and variations and none worked):

```
package com.example.t.firstapp;

import android.util.Log;

public class Player implements Runnable {

    Thread backgroundThread;
    Metronome m;


    public void start() {
        if (backgroundThread == null) {
            backgroundThread = new Thread(this);
            m = new Metronome();
            backgroundThread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (backgroundThread != null) {
            backgroundThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.i("a", "Thread starting.");
            while (!backgroundThread.isInterrupted()) {
                m.play();
            }
            Log.i("b", "Thread stopping.");
            throw new InterruptedException(); // ???
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // important you respond to the InterruptedException and stop processing
            // when its thrown!  Notice this is outside the while loop.
            Log.i("c", "Thread shutting down as it was requested to stop.");
        } finally {
            backgroundThread = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Note the line marked with "???". I added that one myself because otherwise the "catch (InterruptedException ex)" returned an error.
Here is the relevant code from my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

...

public Player p;

...
    public void play() {
        p = new Player();
        p.start();
    }
    public void stop() {
        p.stop();
    }
}
```

Calling p.stop(); from within the method 'stop' doesn't actually do anything. This is where I get stuck. If I call p.stop() immediately after I start the thread, like this:

```
public void play() {
    p = new Player();
    p.start();
    p.stop();
}
```

Then it works, and I see all of the relevant log messages from the Player class. Why doesn't p.stop() work when I call it from my 'stop' method? Is it because I am calling it from a different method, or is it because I am not calling it immediately?

Any help would be greatly appreciated since this is extremely frustrating. I have been studying and practicing Android development for only a week now, but I haven't done anything over the last 5 days but try to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: What does `m.play()` do? Does it return immediately?

Comment: m.play() doesn't return immediately, it's a 'while' loop. Does that have something to do with it? Do I need to break the loop or something? And if so, how come it works if I call stop immediately after play?

Comment: I can't believe it but it worked... all I did was call m.stop (metronome stop function) before I interrupt the thread. I have no idea how I didn't manage to do that before, even though I definitely have tried it in my previous attempts. This whole thing still really confuses me... Thank you for your comment

Comment: Edited my answer, take a look please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the concept of interruption. Interupting is not some magical way of forcing the thread to stop, rather it will only work for methods that **have interruption support** - like sleeping.

Take a look at the [`Thread#interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) API, where it lists interrupt supported methods:

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the `wait()`, `wait(long)`, or `wait(long, int)` methods of the `Objec`t class, or of the `join()`, `join(long)`, `join(long, int)`, `sleep(long)`, or `sleep(long, int)`, methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an `InterruptedException`.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an **interruptible** channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status will be set, and the thread will receive a `ClosedByInterruptException`.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a `Selector` then the thread's interrupt status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's wakeup method were invoked.
>
> **If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt status will be set.**

You can nicely implement your own methods with interrupt support, by contantly checking for the interrupt status.

---

Now let's see how we can solve your problem.

According to your comment, `m.play()` does not return, meaning, once `m.play()` is called, the `while` never checks if the thread has been interrupted; in turn it will never stop, since `m.play()` *isn't implemented to support interrupts*. This should also explain why the compiler complains that nobody throws an `InterruptedException`. (The reason it worked if interrupted immediately, is that the interrupt status is changed before it reaches the `while`... Think of it.)

Now, I assume that, if you will call `m.stop()`, `m.play()` *will* return, successfully rechecking for thread interruption. That's why it worked, as mentioned in comment.

But look, there's no real use of interrupting the thread - since all you have to do is call `m.stop()` and release the `m.play()`, just play and wait to return - which means stop has been called. Same to the `while` loop, drop it all the way.

```
public void run() {
    Log.i("a", "Thread starting.");

    m.play(); // blocks till stopped from some other thread...
    
    Log.i("b", "Thread stopping.");
    Log.i("c", "Thread shutting down as it was requested to stop.");
   
    backgroundThread = null;
}
```

One case where I may see a use of the `while` and interrupt, if `m.play()` may return earlier than by calling `m.stop()` (say, by some exception), and you want to restart the metronome until stop is called; then a loop may be on the rescue, and interrupt may signal that it was actually stopped by calling `m.stop()`.

```
public void run() {
    Log.i("a", "Thread starting.");
    while (!backgroundThread.isInterrupted()) {
        m.play();
        if(!backgroundThread.isInterrupted())
            Log.i("b", "Stopped by exception, restarting....");
    }

    Log.i("c", "Thread stopping.");
    Log.i("d", "Thread shutting down as it was requested to stop.");

    backgroundThread = null;
}
```